# How can I delete all the columns in a csv file other than the ones I input?

Tags: python, csv

```py
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob("/home/greenvulcano/Scrivania/File_csv/*.csv")]
dest_file = "/home/greenvulcano/Scrivania/Unione_files.csv"

tag = ["inclination","deformation","temperature"]

content = []
for file_name in sorted(all_filenames):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for i, l in enumerate(lines):
        if len(content) == 0:
            content.append(l)
        elif i != 0:
            content.append(l)


with open(dest_file, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(content)    
seleziona = input("Inserisci le colonne che vuoi visualizzare: ")    with open(dest_file, "r") as f:
    titoli = f.readline().split(",")
    indici = []
    for titolo in titoli:
        titolo_split = titolo.split('*')
        if seleziona in titolo_split:
            indice = titoli.index(titolo)
            indici.append(indice)
    righe = f.readlines()
    lista = []
    for riga in righe:
        rigasplit = riga.split(",")
        for i in indici:
            lista.append(rigasplit[i])
```

Comment: Update your question with a couple of the csv lines for testing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like the code is truncated. Are you maybe asking how, if you read in a `.csv` and you then modify it, you want to replace the contents of the file with a new array? That seems like a dangerous approach to data integrity. Perhaps only output your new array to a new file?

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: after joining two or more .csv files, I need to be able to notice only the columns that I input

Comment: what they managed to do (after merging the .csv files), is to select the whole column through the name given as input, but not as well as delete all the other columns

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use:

**test.csv**

```
id,name,dob
1,pedro,2000-01-01
2,nuno,1999-01-01
```

---

```
import csv
csv_file = "test.csv"
seleziona = input("Inserisci le colonne che vuoi visualizzare: ").strip()
with open(csv_file) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[seleziona])
```

---

```
pedro
nuno
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/5d00240b4d)